# Android Studio design preview not corresponding to actual device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview, android-linearlayout

After initial layout desiging in xml *Design* preview tab I run the code on the target device (*Samsung Tab A SM-T550*). To my surprise the sizes and proportions appeared **clearly different from the preview**, especially *TextViews* and *Button*. I noticed that largest difference concerns the *font size* (i.e. the title on the screenshots).

- [Design preview](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhjti43wqjb1c90/layout-2017-01-31-100343.png?dl=0)
- [Screenshot from device](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2p8u1k0w23lwl4c/Screenshot_20170131-100304.png?dl=0)

My config was:

Started with adding custom virtual device in AVD corresponding to screen size (*9,7"*), resolution (*1024x768*), density (*ldpi*) etc. 
For the layout I setted up an .xml file and in *Design* preview tab chosen the newly created device profile.

I've already double checked the resolution, dimension and API level setting. I had no such problems developing Android smartphones. Seems like I'm missing something big here, do you have any clue?

*Layout.xml*:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bialy"
    tools:context="pl.skaner.activity.ShowResultActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title_label"
        tools:text="@string/title_stack"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/czarny" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/outer_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inner_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/transaction_p1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_border">

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/transaction_name"
                    tools:text="SOME TEXT"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/transaction_client"
                    tools:text="DIFFERENT\nTEXT"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/booked_foreign"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        tools:text="100"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:padding="50dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:padding="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="TextView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/booked_symbol"
                            tools:text="USD"
                            android:textSize="50dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/usd"
                            android:id="@+id/booked_flag" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/transaction_p2"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/transaction_p1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_border">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/booked_result">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/booked_rate"
                        tools:text="4,2345"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/booked_national"
                        tools:text="4234,00"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:text="NOWY LEPSZY KURS:"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/new_result_comment"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/new_result"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/new_rate"
                        tools:text="4.234"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/new_national"
                        tools:text="4234,00"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/czarny"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bialy"
        android:id="@+id/netdots"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgGreenDot"
            android:src="@drawable/green_dot"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgRedDot"
            android:src="@drawable/red_dot"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:max="20"
            android:progress="0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="20 s."
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/counter_label"
            android:textColor="@color/czarny"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.skaner"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.7.1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Skaner"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode,face" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MultiTrackerActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Skaner"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ShowResultActivity"
            android:label="Skaner"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MultiTrackerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="pl.skaner.activity.MultiTrackerActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="Skaner Ustawienia"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are using sp. As sp scales according to the user's text settings, the text appears bigger in your device. Change them to dp and see if the problem persists.